# Is this a bug in gcc operator precedence?

Tags: c++, gcc, pass-by-reference

The following code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int change(int *x){
    *x = 4;
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    int z = 10;
    cout << change(&z) << " * " << z << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

produces the following output:

```
0 * 10
```

but I expect:

```
0 * 4
```

and gdb shows that "z = 4" after calling "change" function.

Comment: Operator precedence isn't evaluation order.

Comment: Protip: if very simple code in one of the world's most commonly used compilers doesn't do what you expect, it's almost certainly *not* a bug in the compiler.

Comment: Thanks to @Juhana. It's may not be a bug, but really unexpected.